# How to use autolayout to move a view

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want my subview move to the top and it's superView to shrink, when I remove another subview.

I have a view, called topView. Inside it there are three views : toField, fromField, subjectTextView.

I added following constraints to make this happen, but they do not work: when toField is removed, nothing happens, topView remains the same.

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_fromField, _toField, _subjectTextView);
NSArray *layoutConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_toField][_fromField][_subjectTextView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
[_topView addConstraints:layoutConstraints];
```

I've read [Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/formatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3-SW1), but there is nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Interface Builder set:

top space to superview between `topView` and `_toField`

vertical spacing between `_toField` and `_fromField`

vertical spacing between `_fromField` and `_subjectTextView`

bottom space to superview between `_subjectTetView` and superview (this needs to be negative - say -20.0)

When you hide the `subjectTextView`, just set it's height constraint to 0.0, and `topView` will shrink.